# SqlAlchemy truncate table with ORM

Tags: mysql, orm, sqlalchemy

I have been using orm for my app, and try not to use sql to avoid sql syntax error when changing between different dbms.

At the moment I am testing with sqlite and mysql. I figured out to delete a table we can use:

`db.session.query(models.MyTable).delete()`

Unfortunately this method does not really "truncate" the table, because It does not reset the counting of autoincrement to 0.

Is there anyway to do the real truncate in SqlAlchemy orm ?

Comment: the need to reset sequences is suspicious, why do you want this?

Comment: I want the same behavior between sqlite and mysql because it seems that for sqlite the counter is reset while mysql is not.

Comment: resetting the sequence is more a defect of sqlite's sequence implemenation, I consider it to be a bug!

Comment: There are times people throw in development data in a database for testing purposes, then want to truncate the table and do it again. To me this is a reasonable time to have the counter reset. It's like a "do-over"

Comment: Support for `TRUNCATE` was [requested in 2009](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues/1474) and rejected, due to inconsistencies between RDBMS implementations (as I understand it).

Answer (score 3):

SQLAlchemy `delete(...)` method is translated into SQL `DELETE FROM` query. This query *does not* resets any AUTO_INCREMENT counters. To reset a counter in MySQL you have to run a query like that:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl AUTO_INCREMENT = 100;
```

If I'm not mistaking, it has no analogue in SQLAlchemy.

Answer (score 1):

As there is no `truncate()` operation,  a simple workaround in sqlalchemy for deleting all entries from a table and resetting the autoincrement count is to drop and recreate the table like this:

```
Base.metadata.drop_all(engine, tables=[YourTable.__table__])
Base.metadata.create_all(engine, tables=[YourTable.__table__])
```

(for alternative sqlalchemy syntax examples for dropping a table check this [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35918605/how-to-delete-a-table-in-sqlalchemy))

Comment: This would drop the tables (their schema included), which is slower. Correct me if I'm wrong.