# How to delete a table in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy, drop-table

I want to delete a table using SQLAlchemy.

Since I am testing over and over again, I want to delete the table `my_users` so that I can start from scratch every single time.

So far I am using SQLAlchemy to execute raw SQL through the [engine.execute()](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.Engine.execute) method:

```
sql = text('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_users;')
result = engine.execute(sql)
```

However, I wonder if there is some standard way to do so. The only one I could find is [`drop_all()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.MetaData.drop_all), but it deletes all the structure, not only one specific table:

```
Base.metadata.drop_all(engine)   # all tables are deleted
```

---

For example, given this very basic example. It consists on a SQLite infrastructure with a single table `my_users` in which I add some content.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, Integer, String, text
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

engine = create_engine('sqlite://', echo=False)
Base = declarative_base()

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "my_users"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

# Create all the tables in the database which are
# defined by Base's subclasses such as User
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

# Construct a sessionmaker factory object
session = sessionmaker()

# Bind the sessionmaker to engine
session.configure(bind=engine)

# Generate a session to work with
s = session()

# Add some content
s.add(User('myname'))
s.commit()

# Fetch the data
print(s.query(User).filter(User.name == 'myname').one().name)
```

For this specific case, `drop_all()` would work, but it won't be convenient from the moment I start having more than one table and I want to keep the other ones.

Comment: Note: Must surround sql query in `text(...)` for it to work. If this is omitted, then SQLAlchemy does not work, and it does not give any feedback as to why it did not work.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Just call `drop()` against the table object.
From [the docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Table.drop):

> Issue a DROP statement for this Table, using the given Connectable for connectivity.

In your case it should be:

```
User.__table__.drop()
```

---

If you get an exception like:

> ```
> sqlalchemy.exc.UnboundExecutionError: Table object 'my_users' is not bound to an Engine or Connection. Execution can not proceed without a database to execute against
> ```

You need to pass the engine:

```
User.__table__.drop(engine)
```

Comment: This only works if the table exists, it will give an error if you delete the whole .db file and want to create it again. I made a follow up question to this, please take a look if you want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39493174/how-to-delete-multiple-tables-in-sqlalchemy

Comment: This can't be used in a transaction. I want to rollback a transaction if tables are dropped, but other queries like creating them again raise exceptions. With this I can't do that.

Comment: @KarinaKlinkevičiūtė You can check if the table does (not) exist first; e.g.
`engine = db.engine;
if not engine.dialect.has_table(engine, ModelClass.__tablename__):
    ModelClass.__table__.create(engine)`

Comment: Accessing `db = SQLAlchemy(app)` and then doing `User.__table__.drop(db.engine)` worked for me

Comment: Is there not a public API for this, rather then using a private `__table__` attribute?

Comment: If you find that your call to `User.__table__.drop()` seems to hang/freeze (particularly in Postgres), see solution here: https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues/4685

Comment: @code_dredd I have used a similar syntax in my code but the problem still persists. Getting error : "The argument passed to Dialect.has_table() should be a <class 'sqlalchemy.engine.base.Connection'>, got <class 'sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine'>. Additionally, the Dialect.has_table() method is for internal dialect use only; please use ``inspect(some_engine).has_table(<tablename>>)`` for public API use." Your inputs will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: this is not compatible with sqlalchemy 2

Answer (score 39):

Alternative to calling `cls.__table__.drop(your_engine)`, you can try this:

```
Base.metadata.drop_all(bind=your_engine, tables=[User.__table__])
```

This method as well as the `create_all()` method accept an optional argument `tables`, which takes an iterator of `sqlalchemy.sql.schema.Table` instances.

You can control which tables are to be created or dropped in this way.

Comment: To me, this answer is clearer in semantics.  Creating or dropping tables is more related to database level, so it is better to deal with Base instead of mapping class.  Maybe SqlAlchemy does quite the same thing in the background.

Answer (score 21):

For the special case when you don't have access to the table class and just need to delete the table by table name then use this code

```
import logging
from sqlalchemy import MetaData
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.engine.url import URL
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

DATABASE = {
   'drivername': 'sqlite',
   # 'host': 'localhost',
   # 'port': '5432',
   # 'username': 'YOUR_USERNAME',
   # 'password': 'YOUR_PASSWORD',
   'database': '/path/to/your_db.sqlite'
}

def drop_table(table_name):
   engine = create_engine(URL(**DATABASE))
   base = declarative_base()
   metadata = MetaData(engine, reflect=True)
   table = metadata.tables.get(table_name)
   if table is not None:
       logging.info(f'Deleting {table_name} table')
       base.metadata.drop_all(engine, [table], checkfirst=True)

drop_table('users')
```

Comment: note [a new answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66376565/1983854) was posted mentioning the deprecation of `MetaData(engine, reflect=True)`.

Answer (score 17):

### How to delete a table by name

Here's an update of @Levon's answer, since `MetaData(engine, reflect=True)` is now deprecated. It is useful if you don't have access to the table class or want to delete a table by its table name.

```
from sqlalchemy import MetaData
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.engine.url import URL
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

DATABASE = {
   'drivername': 'sqlite',
   # 'host': 'localhost',
   # 'port': '5432',
   # 'username': 'YOUR_USERNAME',
   # 'password': 'YOUR_PASSWORD',
   'database': '/path/to/your_db.sqlite'
}

engine = create_engine(URL(**DATABASE))

def drop_table(table_name, engine=engine):
    Base = declarative_base()
    metadata = MetaData()
    metadata.reflect(bind=engine)
    table = metadata.tables[table_name]
    if table is not None:
        Base.metadata.drop_all(engine, [table], checkfirst=True)

drop_table('users')
```

### How to delete a table using the table class (preferred)

Otherwise, you may prefer to use `cls.__table__.drop(engine)` and `cls.__table__.create(engine)` instead, e.g.

```
User.__table__.drop(engine)
User.__table__.create(engine)
```

Answer (score 9):

Below is example code you can execute in iPython to test the creation and deletion of a table on Postgres

```
from sqlalchemy import * # imports all needed modules from sqlalchemy

engine = create_engine('postgresql://python:python@127.0.0.1/production') # connection properties stored

metadata = MetaData() # stores the 'production' database's metadata

users = Table('users', metadata,
Column('user_id', Integer),
Column('first_name', String(150)),
Column('last_name', String(150)),
Column('email', String(255)),
schema='python') # defines the 'users' table structure in the 'python' schema of our connection to the 'production' db

users.create(engine) # creates the users table

users.drop(engine) # drops the users table
```

You can also preview my article on Wordpress with this same example and screenshots: oscarvalles.wordpress.com (search for SQL Alchemy).