# NameError when dropping table in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, psql

A follow up from [How to delete a table in SQLAlchemy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35918605/how-to-delete-a-table-in-sqlalchemy)

I want to drop a table `User_test` but when doing so I constantly get a `NameError`

I have defined the table with a python class called `User`. 
Though I have forgotten how I defined its columns so I run the following `User class` and leave out the column definitions

```
engine = create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://user:password@localhost/test')
Base = declarative_base(engine)

class User(Base):
   __tablename__ = 'User_test'
   __table_args__ = {'autoload':True}
```

But when I try to drop the User_test table (by trying out any of the following commands):

```
Base.metadata.drop_all(bind=engine, tables=[User_test.__table__])
Base.metadata.drop_all(tables=User_test)
User_test.drop(engine)
User_test.__table__.drop(engine)
User_test.__table__.drop(self._engine)
```

I get:

```
"Nameerror: name "User_test" is not defined"
```

Though when I run `print(engine.table_names())` in python I can see the table.
And when running `print(Base.metadata.tables.keys())` I see the table included

I also can see the table when querying the database through psql  (ie running run `\dt` in psql) 
Though when I try to run a select on the table in psql ie `(Select * from User_test);`

I get:

```
"Could not find a relationship with name User_test"
```

My questions are:

- Why do I get a NameError when trying to drop the table in python and
  how can I fix it?
- Why can I not perform a Select query on the table in psql when I clearly can see it?
- Do I need to have the User class defined with all the Column names, is that why all this is happening?

Thank you

Comment: The model is called `User` not `User_test` so `User.__table__.drop(engine)` looks to be the correct command as per the documentation: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/metadata.html#creating-and-dropping-database-tables

Comment: Thank you very much, I misread the documentation.

But do you know why I can't access the table from psql? I.e I can see the table when running "\dt" but when I run "Select * from user_test" then I get an error, would you happen to have an idea why?

thanks