# Dropping a table created by df.to_sql()

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a flask application with a background process I have spawned away from the GUI.  I have a db session created in association with the Flask app.  Because I want to have the freedom to write tables to the db that are not necessarily to be referenced by GUI code, I am not creating the overhead of a class.

The code that creates a table is as follows:

```
admin_df.to_sql(df_name, con=db.engine, if_exists="replace")
```

How would I now delete this table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer I needed is based upon Levon's reply at:

[How to delete a table in SQLAlchemy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35918605/how-to-delete-a-table-in-sqlalchemy)

Basically, this did the trick:

```
from sqlalchemy import MetaData
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from [code location] import db

Base = declarative_base()
metadata = MetaData(db.engine, reflect=True)
table = metadata.tables.get(table_name)
table_to_delete = metadata.tables.get('table_name_for_table_to_delete')
Base.metadata.drop_all(db.engine, [table_to_delete])
```